# ford focus 2003 new starter stays engaged new ignition switch,new wire harness to starter how to test starter relay

Tags: ford, starter, focus, relay

I have a 2003 Ford Focus. I recently installed a new starter motor, a new ignition switch, and a new wiring harness. The starter now stays engaged when I try and start the car. How do I check the starter relay, or otherwise find problem?

Comment: Which engine do you have and what's the 8th VIN character?